# Using socket.io and express, why isn't my io.on('connection') method working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm trying to teach myself socket.io and node.js by following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tzNOqcoupWQ

This is the code that's written by the end of the turotial:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.Port || 3000;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
})

server.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('Listening on port ' + port);

    io.on('connection', function(socket){
        console.log('User Connected! :)');

        //handle a new message
        socket.on('new:message', function(msgObj){
            io.emit('new:message', msgObj);
        });

        //handle a new member joining
        socket.on('new:member', function(name){
            io.emit('new:member', name);
        });
    })
});
```

The problem is, it seems the io.on('connection' method isn't going through and the "User connected!" message isn't being printed out to the console, yet my index.html loads up just fine (it's just a simple header for now).

What can I do to solve this?

[EDIT]
Here's the index.html

```
<h1>Hello, World!</h1>
```

Comment: Please provide the "index.html code" also

Comment: As I said in the bottom, it's a just a simple header that says "Hello, World!" for now.

Comment: It's possible that way your using the socket.io client API is incorrect, so would be good to include the javascript in index.html as well

Comment: Is there a client side code to help more?

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://socket.io/docs/client-api/

Comment: No, this is all that was made in the first part of the tutorial. It seems to work in the tutorial, I just can't get it to work on my machine.

Comment: @user2953932 That tutorial is bad. The author doesn't know extremely basic things, and it looks like he's pretending to write all the code on the fly, but he's clearly re-typing it off another screen or printout, making mistakes in the process. I'd also advise to learn node, then express, then socket.io. Not all three at once.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'll look into better tutorials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to include the client side socket. i.e add the below code in your html file being served.

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io();
</script>
```

*Integrating Socket.IO* in the [documentation](https://socket.io/get-started/chat) is a good place to start.

Comment: This was it! thank you so much! 
And just fo clarification, what exactly is that script src?

Comment: A client library that loads on the browser side: socket.io-client (It can be achieved either like above or by importing 'socket.io-client' package )